# Changing item in list after loop

Tags: python

I have created a script to log into gmail using selenium. I want the code the script to add 1 to the variable count after each time the program loops. This is so it uses a different email addresses the second time the program loops.

PLEASE NOTE: the `for x in range(0, 2):` needs to remain there as it is for the whole script, not just this part.

If you need more information, feel free to ask

```
  for x in range(0, 2):
        count = 0
        emails = ['myemail1@gmail.com', 'myemail2@gmail.com']
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys(emails[count])
```

Comment: You already got your index key through `x`. Just use it. You could also initialize your email array outside of the loop and iterate over this array to get the emails directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
count=0
for x in range(0,2):
        emails = ['myemail1@gmail.com', 'myemail2@gmail.com']
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys(emails[count])
        count = count + 1
```

Comment: this uses both emails: myemail1@gmail.commyemail2@gmail.com is what is typed in. I need it to show myemail1@gmail.com on the first loop, then on the second loop myemail2@gmail.com @Umair

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in range(0, 2):
        emails = ['myemail1@gmail.com', 'myemail2@gmail.com']
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys(emails[x])
```

delete count and cycle through the for loop